# collective.z3cform.datagridfield Dexterity and behavior

Tags: plone, dexterity, z3c.form

I am working on an behavior for Dexterity and I use collective.z3cform.datagridfield for it.

This should it be:

```
+----+-------+----+  
| title | value | link |  
+----+-------+----+  

tile = schema.TextLine  
value = schema.TextLine  
link = schema.Choice (Related Widget)
```

This is my Code:

```
class IDifferentiation(form.Schema):
    title = schema.TextLine(title=_(u'Title for this element', default=u'Title for this element'), required=True)
    value = schema.TextLine(title=_(u'Text for this element', default=u'Text for this element'), required=False)

    form.widget(downloads=RelatedItemsFieldWidget)
    link = schema.Choice(
        title=_(u"Person"),
        source=UUIDSourceBinder(),
        required=True)

class IDifferentiationBox(form.Schema):
    """ """
    form.widget(differentiation=DataGridFieldFactory)
    differentiation = schema.List(
            title=_(u"Differentiation"),
            value_type=DictRow(title=_(u"Facts"), schema=IDifferentiation)
    )
```

But for the "link"-Field, i only get a Select-Dropdown, or a In-Out-Widget (depends on the used Widget), with no data/Contenttypes to select.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that `form directives` as you use does no work on your `IDifferentiation` interface. Since it's no a z3c.form , it's a datagrid subform.

But collective.z3cform.datagridfield added some entry points to modify it's behavior.

The package [`example.conference`](https://github.com/collective/example.conference) adds different widget to specific datagrid subform fields by overriding the add/edit form and view template.

First you need to register your two templates as shown [here](https://github.com/collective/example.conference/blob/aad548c4a98d4edf5e7d5e6bb18c6300fbdd5f9a/example/conference/configure.zcml#L29-L41)

```
<browser:page
    for="plone.dexterity.interfaces.IDexterityContent"
    name="differentiationbox_edit"
    class=".ifferentiationbox.DataGridEditView"
    permission="cmf.ModifyPortalContent"
    />

<browser:page
    for="plone.dexterity.interfaces.IDexterityContent"
    name="ifferentiationbox_view"
    class=".ifferentiationbox.DataGridView"
    permission="zope2.View"
    />
```

Second, change the widget for the [datagrid subform fields](https://github.com/collective/example.conference/blob/615d3abfedf905fdb4fc3e04ba4266e3336b6f48/example/conference/attendee.py#L130-L164)
In only show one example (edit form) in this answer since it's the same for the add form and the view template.

```
class DataGridEditView(DefaultEditForm):
    """Edit form that uses the ContentTreeWidget for some fields in
    the datagrids.
    """

    def datagridInitialise(self, subform, widget):
        if widget.name == 'form.widgets.differentiation':
            subform.fields['link'].widgetFactory = ContentTreeFieldWidget
```

So this adds the `ContentTreeFieldWidget` to your datagrid subform field `link`.

Comment: Hi,
I already tried example.conference, but it doesn't work for me and as dexterity behavior.

Comment: What did not work? Any Traceback? Does the example.conference package work for you without any modifications?

Comment: Sorry, no Traceback, nothing - only an empty Select-Dropdown.

No, example.conference does also not work

Comment: I saw the example.conference in action at a conference. But it was build for Plone 4.1 and DX 1.x. Is your package public? In order to help, the simplest way would be to boostrap/buildout your package on my machine.

Comment: No, sorry it isn't public  

I'll try to make a custom buildout, to test - until weekend

- I use plone4.3 and dx2

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem not simply a wrong field name in this line?:

```
form.widget(downloads=RelatedItemsFieldWidget)
```

should rather be

```
form.widget(link=RelatedItemsFieldWidget)
```